# How does the number of GPUs impact batch_size in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using Tensorflow and feed my data to the network using *FIFO Queues*. In the end my code uses `tf.train.shuffle_batch(..)` to generate the batches which I feed to my network. If I set my `batch_size = 4` and my number of GPUs are lets say 4 as well. Would the actual `batch_size` be 16 or how does the number of GPUs impact the `batch_size` or what is the benefit of having more than one GPU?

Comment: Tensorflow only uses one GPU on default. If you want to use more than one you need to define the device placements. e.g., "with tf.device('/gpu:0'):" Here's an example https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/5_MultiGPU/multigpu_basics.py

Comment: Hm when I do not use tf.device(...) it tells me in the log that it found 4 GPUs tho, so why is that? But yeah, my question would still be would it affect the batch size? @gidim

Comment: It found 4 gpus but it's only using one. you can validate that with nividia-smi.
As for the batch size- if you're assigning different ops to different GPUs it won't matter.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I think I checked and it said that all GPUs are using a lot of memory... @gidim

Comment: Can you paste your nvidia-smi output?

Comment: @thigi this is normal. All GPU memory will show a high utilization. Use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` to only use the first GPU and you'll see the effect.